flutter launcher icons doesnt work and in cant understand why
i write in vsc.
the probelm is when i download the apk to my phone adn trying to download the app app doesnt being downloadde and the packege installer is being crashed i found the problem with the image i create witht the flutter launcher icons. when i try to download the app there is no image its white background. i created an app before using the flutter launcher icons and it worked i did the same steps even copied the code tried few different images and it doesnt work! anyone know why?? in the android.manifest when i set the icon to the deadult flutter icon its downbloading the app but when i set it to th eicon that was created by the flutter launcher icons it crashed and doesnt download it/
please help!
..............................

Can you share your flutter_launcher_icon's config

The problem is with Android Studio "LadyBug" version. It has some conflicts with default gradle plugin. Easy way is delete all gradle and android studio caches, then install android studio Koala version and try again.
EDIT:
Just downgrade plugin to 0.13.1 version:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

